# TypeScript function that returns value for string literal of property name?

Tags: typescript, types, key

Consider this TypeScript function that returns the value of an objects property:

```
export function getProperty<T>(object: T, key: string): any {
    return (object as any)[key]
}
```

It is not very nice to use, since it always returns an `any`:

```
interface Animal {
    name: string,
    hungry: boolean,
}

const myHippo: Animal = {
    name: "Hippo",
    hungry: true,
}

const name = getProperty(myHippo, "name") // Returns any, but I want a string.
const size = getProperty(myHippo, "size") // Returns any, but I want a compiler error.
```

I would like it to return a value with the correct type, e.g. `string` for `"name"`, and cause a compiler error if the string literal provided in `key` is not a property of `object`. (I do not need to support non literal strings, those can be compiler errors too.)

Is this even possible with TypeScript? I suspect not, but I am not sure.

Something that would be useful as a step in the right direction would be an utility type `Keys<T>` that represent the union of all string literals that are property names in `T`. But that doesn't seem to exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return object[key];
}
```

This gives you the compiler failure you want and the return type matches the property type

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwObAwAKUEYwsAngDwAqANHANJygzAoAmAznANbBKEBHFoA+ABQQARgCtgGAFyjGAysqYBKZbQDaTALpwA3gCg4FuFEJIouGfIy61B0wF9TpzCnZQEAQzRgOABBFEwAW38AGxNzSxR-COBlbhgobzx6eIsAC1Q8KHU4aQgIaOB-FGyPUzQcNLgIygAJTDBIZTDImLgAXjjLOETk5QAiNo6IMeyh-JRC4vSkYBrPepRGkeCBgmJScioJZsnIRjHtsc04AHobuAAlGzteNIyFuob4bkwALx38IQSGQKDBKMdWu0znAxj9-ldbvd6hEwJgKlBWFBSFAAHRAA)